# Is this a single cycle circuit?

Tags: fpga, quartus-ii

To find the Fmax of a circuit designed using VHDL you need to have a register to register path. Because of this however, it takes 2 clock cycles to get the correct output after inputting some data. Is it correct to call this design a single cycle circuit then?
[image]

Comment: I don't follow the logic.. *"..it takes 2 clock cycles..."*, "*.. this design a single cycle circuit then.."*. How *2* is *single*?

Comment: I am also confused, the problem is: how could you ever have single cycle circuits that show the Fmax if you can't have the registers?

Comment: you can have just one register...

Comment: But you need a register-to-register path for Fmax, so one register won't work?

Comment: Well, this is a single-cycle datapath after all, as the calculation is taking a single cycle, and each cycle you can have a new input data and the new output data. You better pull out your definition of a single-cycle circuit.

Comment: The stuff in between the registers is single-cycle. But you need the registers to do the calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you define 'single cycle circuit'.  In general, your circuit will be fed by registers and it will feed registers, so usually you're only interested in the delay between the registers and not the delay of the registers themselves as this determines the minimum clock period.

There are really two important metrics here: throughput and latency.  Throughput is determined by how often a circuit can accept new data and/or produce a new result.  In this case, your circuit can accept a new input and produce a new output on every clock cycle.  Latency is determined by how long it takes to propagate a set of data through the circuit.  In this case, the latency between the input and output registers is one cycle.

It is possible to build circuits that have lower throughput and higher latency.  Let's say you double the clock frequency.  In this case, you can only change the input and store the output every other clock cycle.  So the throughput is 1/2 as only half of the clock cycles can be used to transfer in data, and the latency is 2 cycles as it takes 2 cycles for data from the input register to end up in the output register.  How about adding a pipeline register in the middle of the operation?  This would keep the throughput at 100% as the intermediate result can be stored in the pipeline register on every cycle, but the latency would be 2 cycles because it takes two cycles to get the data from the input, through the pipeline register, to the output register.

So for your circuit, I think that if you consider just the delay between data getting clocked out of the input register to the result getting clocked in to the output register, 'single cycle circuit' is a succinct way to describe it.